# create oracle transaction using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, transactions

I am using oracle transaction to insert into **multi-tables**  one master table and two details tables at the same time. so i will insert one record to the master table and multi-records to the other two tables.
i need to return value 1 if the operation success in all tables, if error occurs i will return 0,and 3 if the data already exist in the master table. I need to do this in c#, here is my code,
and how i can modify my code to insert to other tables using loops

```
public int RunOracleTransaction(Student s, Marks[] m, Course []s)
{
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    OracleTransaction transaction;

    // Start a local transaction
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    try
    {
      // what i shall do to insert 1 record to master data and multi records //to details data as one transaction ?
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Neither record was written to database.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You will certainly need to instantiate `OracleTransaction`; you should also make use of a using block to ensure it completes. Call `Commit` to avoid rollback.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost implemented it:

```
public int RunOracleTransaction(Student s, Marks[] m, Course[] c) {
  //TODO: validate s, m, c

  using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();

    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
      using (OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)) {
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try {
          // Insert the student
          //TODO: put actual query here 
          command.CommandText = 
            @"insert into Students(name)
                   values (:prm_Name)
                returning id into :prm_id"; // <- we want inserted student's id

          //TODO: check actual RDBMS types 
          command.Parameters.Add(":prm_Name", OracleType.VarChar).Value = s.Name;
          command.Parameters.Add(":prm_Id", OracleType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         
          command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

          string studentId = Convert.ToString(comm.Parameters[":prm_Id"].Value);
         
          // Insert his/her marks
          command.Parameters.Clear(); // <- forget all prior parameters

          //TODO: put actual query here 
          command.CommandText = 
            @"insert into StudentsMarks(student_Id, mark)
                   values (:prm_Student_Id, :prm_Mark)";

          //TODO: check actual RDBMS types 
          command.Parameters.Add(":prm_Student_Id", OracleType.VarChar).Value = studentId;
          command.Parameters.Add(":prm_Mark", OracleType.Int32);
          
          // insert each mark (in a loop)
          foreach (var mark in m) {
            command.Parameters[":prm_Mark"].Value = m.Mark;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
          }

          // Finally, commit all the inserts
          transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (DataException e) {
          transaction.Rollback();

          Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
          Console.WriteLine("Neither record was written to database.");
        }
      }
    } 
  }

  //TODO: your method returns integer value, please return it  
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives me the following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". when trying to define the transaction **OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)**

Comment: Yup, 2023 and still having the same error. I am afraid the Oracle driver has some problems.